# Creating buttons in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, button, xcode5, segue

Is there a better way to do the following in Xcode for iPhone app?

I have a main navigation UIViewController screen with 4 buttons on it.

Clicking button 1 shows a sub navigation UIViewController with 4 buttons on it.
Clicking button 2 shows the same sub navigation UIViewController but with 5 buttons on it.
Clicking button 3 shows the same sub navigation UIViewController but with 4 buttons on it.
Clicking button 4 shows the same sub navigation UIViewController but with 6 buttons on it.

To handle this I have assigned tags to each button in the main navigation.
When a button is clicked, I take this tag number and pass it to sub navigation UIViewController.

Then in the sub navigation UIViewController, based on this value, I manually draw/create the sub navigation buttons as needed.

Below is how I handle this in the sub navigation UIViewController.
I check to see what value was passed from main navigation UIViewController, and draw the number of buttons accordingly. I also set custom background images for each button. And for each button click I have its own selector method. Note that some buttons in the sub navigation will go to a UIViewController while some buttons will go to a TableViewController. Also each sub navigation button will have to display its own "content" in its destination view.

Is there a better, more elegant way of handling this? It just seems like a lot of code duplication to me.The example below shortened for brevity.

```
//  SubNavViewController.m
//  SegueTest
#import "SubNavViewController.h"
#import "GettingHereViewController.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "GettingHereContent.h"

@interface SubNavViewController ()
@end

@implementation SubNavViewController
@synthesize tagNumber;
@synthesize buttonNumber;
@synthesize buttonPushedTrackNumber;

@synthesize hotelButton;
@synthesize bAndBButton;
@synthesize caravanButton;
@synthesize selfCateringButton;
@synthesize apartmentsButton;
.
.
.
etc (19 in total)


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    } 
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.tagNumber == 1)
    {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Getting Here";

        // By Air Button
        byAirButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        byAirButton.tag = 1;
        byAirButton.frame = CGRectMake(25, 140, 280.f, 40.f);
        UIImage *airButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gettingHereByAirButton.png"];
        [byAirButton setBackgroundImage:airButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:byAirButton];
        [byAirButton addTarget:self action:@selector(byAirButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // By Rail Button
        byRailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        byRailButton.tag = 2;
        byRailButton.frame = CGRectMake(25, 190, 280.f, 40.f);
        UIImage *railButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gettingHereByRailButton.png"];
        [byRailButton setBackgroundImage:railButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:byRailButton];
        [byRailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(byRailButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        .
        .
        . etc (2 more button)
    }
    else if (self.tagNumber == 2)
    {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Where to Stay";

        // B&B Button
        bAndBButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        bAndBButton.tag = 1;
        bAndBButton.frame = CGRectMake(25, 140, 280.f, 40.f);
        UIImage *bedAndBreakfast = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whereToStayBedAndBreakfastButton.png"];
        [bAndBButton setBackgroundImage:bedAndBreakfast forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:bAndBButton];
        [bAndBButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bAndBButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        .
        .
        . etc (do this for the rest of the buttons)  
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) byAirButtonClicked
{
    GettingHereContent *gettingHere = [GettingHereContent new];
    gettingHere = @"By Air";
    NSLog(@"Content: %@", gettingHere);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gettingHereSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void) bAndBButtonClicked
{
    GettingHereContent *gettingHere = [GettingHereContent new];
    gettingHere = @"Bed and Breakfast";
    NSLog(@"Content: %@", gettingHere);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tableViewSegue" sender:self];
}

.
.
. (do this for all buttons - 19 in total)

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
}
@end
```

Comment: How much this can be simplified depends on whether there's any overlap in your 4 sub navigation view controllers. Do some of them have the same buttons as some other ones? Do some of the buttons segue to the same controllers, or are they all different? One thing you can simplify is to delete all the @synthesize statements, they're no longer needed.

Comment: All buttons will be different but most of them will segue to the same controller. Only 4 buttons will segue to a different controller . Also I tried deleting all the @synthesize statements, but got a load of errors so will leave them in for now.

Comment: You probably got those errors because you are referring to your properties as hotelButton, for instance -- you need to use self.hotelButton if you are accessing the property, or _hotelButton if you want to access the backing ivar directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend to create a NS_ENUM defining all your buttons in the following way:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ButtonTag)
{
    ButtonTagHotel,
    ButtonTagOther,
    ...
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad: you could create an Array with all buttons, that are needed for your current state like the following way:

```
NSMutableArray *buttonTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (self.tagNumber == 1 || self.tagNumber == 3)
    [buttonTags addObject: @(ButtonTagHotel)];

if (self.tagNumber == 5 || self.tagNumber == 8)
    [buttonTags addObject: @(ButtonTagOther)];

// etc...
```

When you have build up your needed button tags, you can create and add them all in one loop:

```
uint cnt = 0;

for (NSNumber *tag in buttonTags)
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.tag = [tag unsignedIntValue];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(25, 20 + (cnt * 50.f), 280.f, 40.f);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"genericButtonImage.png"];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cnt++;
}
```

If you have to set a different image for every button, then you should create another array that is holding all image names indexed by the ButtonTag enum...

Now you just have to implement -(void)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)sender:

```
-(void)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)sender
{
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case ButtonTagHotel:
        {
            // do your stuff
        }
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```